# \begin{framed} with background-color

Tags: framed

Does anybody know how to set the background-color of a framed element?

```
\begin{framed}       
    Let me have a background :( 
\end{framed}
```

Comment: switch to `mdframed` package instead. Can do a lot more including frames and colored bgs with easy configuration.

Comment: BTW: next time please provide a minimal example so we can see what kind of preamble you are using

Comment: Besides `framed` and `mdframed` there is also `tcolorbox` to create colored boxes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Defining a background colour is pretty easy if using the `mdframed` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    
    test
    
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20] 
        In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs.
    \end{mdframed}
            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

The [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) is your friend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded*}
    Let me have a background :(
\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

[image: colour]

Comment: With this solution the frame border is lost

Comment: @Ian Thompson: If you load xcolor with, say,  the `x11names` option, you can use `\colorlet{shadecolor}{Red1}`, which one may find a more expressive syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Two solutions with the `framed` package with a `frameborder` and a `framecolor`: I define the `frshaded` and `frshaded*` environments. Rule thickness and distance between text and frame can be easily changed.

```
    \documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{Red1}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newenvironment{frshaded}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
    \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

    \newenvironment{frshaded*}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

    \begin{document}

    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text text

    \begin{frshaded}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{frshaded}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
    \setlength\FrameRule{1.5pt}
    \begin{frshaded*}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{frshaded*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]