# Rectangular framing some relations

Tags: tables

[image: desired framed output]

How can I create a rectangular frame around some relations?

Comment: Please down-voters... (S)he is a new member. Just leave a comment if you down-vote... and remember that one vote down shows a problem... More shows problem in the down-voters! @SawairaArshad please add a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimal-working-example-mwe) . Also, check here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/beginframed-with-background-color

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you place an `aligned` environment inside a `\boxed` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' env. and '\boxed' and '\text' commands
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman fonts)
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}} % handy shortcut command

\begin{document}

\[
\boxed{\begin{aligned}
\text{function $f\colon\R\to\R$}
   &\Leftrightarrow 
   \text{linear transformation $T_A\colon\R^n\to\R^m$} \\
\text{input $x\in\R$} 
   &\Leftrightarrow
   \text{input $\vec{x}\in\R^m$} \\
\cdots &\Leftrightarrow \cdots \\
\text{range of $f$}
   &\Leftrightarrow
   \text{$\mathcal{C}(A)\equiv{}$column space of $A={}$range of $T_A$}
\end{aligned}}
\]

\end{document}
```